# How to load images saved in a shared folder in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

```
<img width="118px" height="180px" src="{{book.imageUri}}" />


book.imageUri="\\someServer\images\9780352347893.jpg"
```

It didn't work out on the Angular page but if copy that image uri into chrome it displayed.

Comment: Didn't work isn't specific enough to ask for help.

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It didn't work out" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-src` not `src` with the `<img>` tag.

Check the docs for [ngSrc directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Comment: Thank you but the chrome console says the error is " Not allowed to load local resource: file://xxx/images/9780857053893.jpg"

Comment: Are the first two slashes throwing it off? Try removing one or both of the initial slashes and see if that will load the image.

Comment: Are you running your html on a web server? You need to do that